# replace string pattern(<, >) in a text using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, str-replace

I had a text **BODY BUTTER (<)&(>) CHERRY - 200ML_XM A0 2208**. I try to replace **(<)&(>)** with **&**.

```
var str = "BODY BUTTER (<)&(>) CHERRY - 200ML_XM A0 2208";
str.replace(/\(<\)|\(>\)/gi,'');
```

It is not working. Is there anyway to get this work?

Comment: `str = str.repl....`

Comment: It is not working for me. can you explain how to make this work. It replace (, ) only. It is not replacing < or >

Comment: It's working. Please check [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/kpgu87ws/). You've to assign the returned string from replace to the `str`.